# How to secure database (encrypted) password on Android?

Tags: android, database, security, password-protection

I have a database containing private information that must only be accessible to my application. I added my database file in assets folder which gets copied over to applications database directory on first time the app runs but "assets" directory and "data" directory(on rooted devices) can be accessed by any other application So I decided to encrypt the database. Android default SQLite Database doesn't provide encryption of the data so I decided to use SQLCipher for android http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-for-android/.

Now I have successfully encrypted the database and I can access it using the specific password. But problem remains... Where should I store this password? so that it can only be accessible to my application.

1. Can't hardcode it as it will be accessible after decompiling it even if it is obfuscated.
2. Can't store it in the file system either (assets/raw)
3. Can't ask the user to enter it as the user could be a hacker

It is standalone app with no server interaction at all

Comment: If you see the user as an attacker, you can't trust anything on the client. Simple as that. You can just throw tons of obfuscation at the problem, and then hope that nobody bothers to break it.

Comment: Why no server interaction? Unless you really have a good reason not to, you should use a server to store the key in my opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Can't ask the user to enter it as the user could be a hacker` Then you have no way to securely store it. For the same reasons you've already identified, specifically that your code can be decompiled, any place you store it that is accessible can be figured out through decompilation and hence retrieved by any code with the right access.

Something the user provides is stored wherever the user stores it -- presumably in his or her head. This is not something software can access, which makes it ideal for reducing the risk of a malware attack. If the entered password is valid, you have no way to know if the user is authorized or not, however you can define policy such as a minimum key length, a maximum number of entry attempts (before introducing some delay or other lockout), etc.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how accurate this answer is but still posting it because I want some response from Android geeks

Considering C code is difficult to decompile, I wrote a simple native C library(.so) using Android NDK which contains an algorithm to generate password. That algorithm is only executed if the app is signed by my certificate. If someone resuse this library in any other app it wont return the password as the certificate won't match.  I got this idea from this post: 
http://digital-identity.dk/2010/12/protecting-ip-in-android-applications/

This is how I  get the certificate:

```
void Java_dk_digitalidetity_android_SomeClass_SomeMethod(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
   // this.getPackageManager()
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
    jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
   jobject packageManager = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);

  // this.getPackageName()
   mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
   jstring packageName = (jstring) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, obj, mid);

  // packageManager->getPackageInfo(packageName, GET_SIGNATURES);
   cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, packageManager);
   mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "getPackageInfo", "(Ljava/lang/String;I)Landroid/content/pm/PackageInfo;");
   jint flags = GET_SIGNATURES;
   jobject packageInfo = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, packageManager, mid, packageName, flags);

  // packageInfo->signatures
   cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, packageInfo);
   jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "signatures", "[Landroid/content/pm/Signature;");
   jobject signatures = (*env)->GetObjectField(env, packageInfo, fid);

 // signatures[0]
   jobject signature = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env, signatures, 0);

 // signature->toByteArray()
   cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, signature);
   mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "toByteArray", "()[B");
   jbytearray certificate = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, signature, mid);
}
```

Comment: Code in a shared object is considered by some to be easier to attack because the debugger lets you stage a scenario to walk through it easily. This is assisted by being able to write a pure C program to attach to and call your shared code, disassemble it, and make changes to the code on the fly. Once the right changes are identified, the binary can be hacked and since Android has no signature on elf images, the attacker (with the right abilities) has fewer hurdles to overcome. It only takes one successful attacker to break the scheme.

Comment: C Shared object has a built in check inside that matches the signature of app. If someone else calls it will never hit the sensitive code. How come someone debug that code that never gets executed?

Comment: you're talking about the signature of your apk, I'm talking about the fact that the libXXX.so native extension is unsigned. When your app is installed, its native library is extracted to the file system and never referred to inside the apk again. Regarding the apk signature check though -- someone that can modify the .so is equally able to modify it to disable the apk signature check, and since this code probably goes through the JNI interface back into the VM, it's relatively easy to locate.